# Discord.js change embed color without erasing all other content

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello im curreently trying to fetch an Embed and then chaging its color

However this erases all other embed contents

```
await msg.channel.messages.fetch("msgID")
        .then(message => {
            const embedsend = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#7bf542')
            message.edit({ embeds: [embedsend] })
        })
        .catch(console.error);
```

This is how I fetch the message and edit the embed what am I doing wrong ?

Im also forced to set a description otherwise I am getting a discord API exception

Comment: Which content? You're just setting Color.

Comment: Things such as fields images etc and it also forced you to override the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating a new embed, use [the embed of the message you fetched](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds).

```js
(message) => {
  const embed = message.embeds[0]
    .setColor('#7bf542');
  message.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
}
```

Comment: Youre right I was a bit confused since the discord.js Documentation stated that I needed to pass a new Embed 

thank you